# SVG viewBox and transform matrix on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg

I need a SVG image to fill a div wrapper and make a zoom effect, so the SVG image is bigger than the div wrapper but the image part that is outside the div wrapper is cropped.

I have the code:

```
<div style="width: 1903px; height: 728.382px;" class="svg-wrapper">
    <svg height="100%" width="100%" id="svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1587.99609375 607.8125">
        <g transform="matrix(1.5625,0,0,1.5625,-796.62390136719,-270.947265625)" id="draw">
            <!-- svg contents -->
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

It works perfectly on Firefox and Google Chrome but it fails on Internet Explorer. The part that is outside the div wrapper is still visible.

This is a Google Chrome screenshot:
[image]

And this is an Internet Explorer screenshot:
[image]

You can notice that the image is floating outside the div wrapper.

How can I render the SVG image inside the div wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add overflow="hidden" to the <svg> element. IE's default value is different to other UAs.